# ASP.NET MVC Select list value using key

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am still reasonably new to C# and trying to understand list objects.

I have a list object with key/value pairs in it, populated from a database (that part is working). I then want to select a value from that list,  using the 'key'. From what I have read I think Linq might be the best way to do this, however I cannot quite work out the syntax I need.

I have a list object as follows:

```
// Create a list of Items from the database, where Value is the 'key' and Text is the 'value'
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ItemList = dbLists.ItemList.Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.Description, Value = x.Id.ToString() });
```

I then want to populate another variable with the description of the selected item in the model, where the model only saves the id.
I have tried various linq `Where` and `Select` queries, but cannot work it out.

The easiest way I can think to explain what I am trying to achieve is to use sql syntax,

```
string SelectedItemDescription = SELECT Text FROM ItemList WHERE ItemList.Value = model.ItemCode
```

An example of a scenario would be something like:

```
ItemList 
{
(Value = "1", Text = "Item 1"),
(Value = "2", Text = "Item 2"),
(Value = "3", Text = "Item 3"),
...
};
model.ItemCode = 2;
// How do I make:
SelectedItemDesctiption = "Item 2";
```

Hopefully that makes sense..

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do like this in LINQ, if you write it this way:

```
string SelectedItemDescription = (from list in ItemList 
                                 where list.Value = model.ItemCode
                                 select list.Text).FirstOrDefault();
```

or you can Use Extension Methods, If it will always return a single element then you can use `SingleOrDefault()`:

```
SelectListItem SelectedItemDescription = ItemList.SingleOrDefault(item=>item.Value == model.ItemCode);

if(SelectedItemDescription !=null)
    {        

        string Key =  SelectedItemDescription .Value;
        string Text = SelectedItemDescription.Text;
    }
```

If it will return a multiple objects then you can use `FirstOrDefault()`:

```
SelectListItem SelectedItemDescription = ItemList.FirstOrDefault(item=>item.Value == model.ItemCode);

if(SelectedItemDescription !=null)
{        

    string Key =  SelectedItemDescription .Value;
    string Text = SelectedItemDescription.Text;
}
```

**UPDATED:**

As @CodeGeek suggested in comments, you can also do like this:

```
string SelectedItemDescription =ItemList
                                .SingleOrDefault(item=>item.Value == model.ItemCode)!=null ? ItemList.SingleOrDefault(item=>item.Value == model.ItemCode).Text : String.Empty;
```

Comment: Your code will throw a null reference exception if that item is not in the list

Comment: `string SelectedItemDescription = ItemList.SingleOrDefault(item=>item.Value == model.ItemCode).Text;`

will do it straight

Comment: @DavidPilkington i am using ``SingleOrDefault``

Comment: @EhsanSajjad from MSDN on `SingleOrDefault` "a default value if the sequence is empty" the default of his object is most likely null

Comment: yes you are right i added null check @DavidPilkington updated

Comment: Thanks @EhsanSajjad It will always only be one item. Both suggestions ended up working, but I went with the CodeGeek suggestion you added as it was all contained in a single line.

Comment: but remeber that will throw null reference exception if item not found

Comment: you have to do like this: ``string SelectedItemDescription =ItemList
                                .SingleOrDefault(item=>item.Value == model.ItemCode)!=null ? ItemList.SingleOrDefault(item=>item.Value == model.ItemCode).Text : String.Empty;``